# Showing that extension of morphism to localization is injective if initial morphism is injective

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S \subseteq R$ a multiplicatively closed set, $X, Y$ be $R$-modules and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism with $\ker f = 0$. $f$ extends to $\tilde f: S^{-1} X \rightarrow S^{-1} Y$, $\tilde f( \frac{x}{s}) = \frac{f(x)}{s}$.

I thought of a proof that $\ker \tilde f = 0$ as well, which seems correct to me, but I'm wondering whether this can be shown more easily - without the local-global principle and Krull's Theorem. The proof I have:

It's easy to see that $S^{-1} \ker f = \ker \tilde f$. By Krull's Theorem, $\exists \mathfrak{m} \in Spec_{Max}(R)$ s.t. $(R \setminus S)_R \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ ( $(R \setminus S)_R$ being the ideal generated). Then $R \setminus \mathfrak{m} \subseteq S$. By transitivity of localization, $S^{-1}( (R \setminus \mathfrak{m})^{-1} \ker f) \simeq S^{-1} \ker f$. By the local global principle, since $\ker f = 0$: $(\ker f)_{\mathfrak{m}} = (R\setminus \mathfrak{m})^{-1} \ker f = 0$ and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be proved directly with the definitions. Let $x\in X$ and $s\in S$, and suppose that $\tilde{f}\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)=0$, ie that $\frac{f(x)}{s}=0$ in $S^{-1}Y$. Then, multiplying through by $\frac{s}{1}$, we get $\frac{f(x)}{1}=0$, so there exists $t\in S$ such that $tf(x)=0$ in $Y$. By $R$-linearity of $f$, this means $f(tx)=0$, whence by injectivity of $f$ we have $tx=0$ in $X$. But this means $\frac{x}{1}=0$ in $S^{-1}X$, whence $\frac{x}{s}=\frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{x}{1}=0$ as well, as desired.